# What does “it’s not going to suck itself ” mean?

Tags: phrases, meaning-in-context, offensive-language

In Goa, I see tourists wearing t-shirts that have the following text on them, along with a red arrow:

> It’s not going to suck itself

What does this mean?

Comment: Presumably the arrow is pointing down?

Comment: So nice that tourism hasn't spoilt Goa

Comment: Avoid these people as you would any other vermin.

Comment: It means "kick me as hard as you can"

Comment: I think questions like these give reason to implement a maturity rating system.

Comment: Someone remove the dating-advice tag. That's not appropriate, much less the question content.

Comment: not sure if serious

Answer (score 11):

Matthew has half the answer. The other half is that "{Noun} isn't going to {verb} itself" is a common phrase implying that a task isn't going to get done unless someone (by implication, the person being spoken to) quits messing around and starts doing it. For example: "These dirty dishes aren't going to clean themselves."

So basically this shirt is supposed to be a "clever" way of suggesting that you should drop whatever you are doing and give the T-shirt wearer oral sex. I'm probably no expert, but I'm guessing he doesn't get many takers...

Comment: When said without being directed at anyone, the phrase is more like an admission of obligation: *(my homework) isn't going to (do) itself* → *I should (do my homework)*.

Comment: @Jon Purdy - Perhaps we should all read the tourist's T-Shirt in that sense then. :-)

Comment: Hah. Somehow I don't think *well, I best get to it* really crosses the mind of that sort of guy.

Answer (score 10):

*It* refers to the genitalia of the (presumably male) person wearing the shirt.

(I hate offensive tourists.)

Comment: For this, we need a word stronger than "offensive." One that rhymes with "whoosh-bag" maybe.

Comment: @TheRaven: You were thinking of axolotl?

Comment: @cerberus what's axolotl?

Comment: @LouisRhys: Eh it's an exotic animal.

Comment: @cerberus does it rhyme with douchebag? I don't get the joke here

Comment: @LouisRhys: I was pretending I didn't know what rhymes with whoosh-bag and suggested an absurd word, since axolotl is a rather uncommon word, and it rhymes with nothing at all (except perhaps a few other Aztec loan words). It wasn't really a funny joke, but there you have it.

Comment: @Louis [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non_sequitur](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non_sequitur).

Answer (score 5):

These t-shirts are apparently not limited to Goa, but appear to be [rather distressingly popular](https://www.google.com/search?client=opera&rls=en&q=t-shirt+it's+not+going+to+suck+itself&sourceid=opera&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&channel=suggest), coming not merely in t-shirts alone:

[image: t-shirt reading: it's not going to suck itself]

but also in many other formats, only a few of which are routinely hidden from the public eye:

[image: boxer underwear reading: it's not going to suck itself]

All these products are saying the same thing: the “it” refers here to a man’s private tackle, so this  a man on the lookout for a new ***fellationship*** [<sup>(Urban Dictionary)</sup>](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=fellationship) — that is, he’s looking for a blow job from someone else.  The phrase “doesn’t suck itself ” further rules out ***autofellatio*** [<sup>(Wikipedia)</sup>](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autofellatio).  It’s extremely coarse advertising in search of a ***fellator*** or ***fellatrix*** to sexually service the fellow.

A slightly less gender-biased variant is occasionally seen, one that might be worn by either men or women because it substitutes *lick* for *suck*:

[image: t-shirt reading: it's not going to lick itself]

Even if the allegorical ice cream cone on the lady’s t-shirt might bring a smile to some viewers, all these products are extremely coarse, and probably offensive to many viewers.

Comment: I think the one on the boxer shorts is kind of cute, actually, as presumably it'll be seen only by people who are likely to appreciate it. The ones on the T-shirt are, frankly, disturbing.